# how store different type of image into database

Tags: c#, sql, image-processing, opencv

After converting a color image to black and white, I want to detect the shape of the image is how i store different type of shape in to database

how can I store each detected shape in a database since image can not store to the database
and how can i store image data to database

Comment: Why is this tagged C# *and* C++? And you *can* store an image in a database (or any binary data, for that matter)... but whether or not you *want* to could be a different story...

Comment: @Uriel_SVK Image processing , pattern rec.. have to store each detected image to DB

Comment: you might consider storing filenames in the actual DB, with the image files in a directory (or directories) somewhere. the path(s) to the directory(s) could also be stored in the DB.

Comment: no i want store image (.jpg/.bmp.etc) files store in DB and compare with input image if input image mach with stored image file data display result

Comment: Explain your problem better, and maybe someone could actually help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well saving picture into db is not very difficult, and can be googled easily

this solution works for me perfectly(for mysql db and png images):

```
MySQLConnection sqlcon;

void savePic(Image pic)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    pic.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    using (MySqlDataAdapter a = new MySqlDataAdapter())
    {
      a.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("insert into images(picture) values (@pic)", sqlcon);
      a.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@pic", (object)ms.ToArray()));
      a.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```

`picture` column in db is type `longblob`

Answer (score -2):

You need to represent image by bitmaps. You can check bitmap at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap